# first option is hidden in the combobox

Tags: jsp, combobox, html-select

I have created a UI page in jsp. I have a combobox in which I need the All option to be selected as default during the first load. It is the second one in the combo and the first is "MY favourites". However my issue is that I cannot see the "My favourites " in the combo.
my code is as follows:

```
function setCategory()
{   
    window.external.getParamFromUsrProfile("templatelistcategory", strCat, false);
    $.ajax({
        url: 'getTempPrPermissions.jsp',
        data:"TrUserId="+TrUserId,       
        type: 'POST',
        success: function(data)
        {       
            var strCategory = "< option value='-1'>My Favorites</option> <option value='0'>All</option>";   
            data = parseXml(data);
            $(data).find("item").each(function() 
            {       
                strCategory +="<option ";
                if(strCat == $(this).find("CategoryId").text())
                {
                    strCategory += " selected=true  ";
                }
                strCategory += "value='"+$(this).find("CategoryId").text()+"'>"+$(this).find("catName").text()+"</option>" ;
            });         
            $("#selectCategory").html(strCategory);            
        }
    });
}
```

The -1 value for "my favourites" option cannot be changed as that is what is expected by the function which uses these values.Please help.

Thanks,
Anita

Comment: Post your html part too. What is the `selectCategory`? (id of your combobox/div?) Also post your response `strCategory`. It should be taken before the line `$("#selectCategory").html(strCategory); `

Comment: @VinothKrishnan selectCategory is the id of my combo and strCategory is a string of options and their values.... I dint understand what you meant by the last line.

Comment: post your final value of `strCategory`.

Comment: <option value='-1'>MY Favourites</option>
<option value='0'>All</option>
<option value='69'>Cardiac</option>
<option value='78'>Neurotic</option>
<option value='88'>Respiratory</option>
<option value='168'>Pulmonary</option>
<option value='141'>ENT</option>

Comment: Instead of trying `$("#selectCategory").html(strCategory);` with this you can try like this `$("#selectCategory").find('option').remove().end().append(strCategory);`

Comment: I dont understand why its not working for u. Check this [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/bbRsf/) for your reference. make sure that your combo box having id as `selectCategory`

Comment: yeah , me neither.. I am calling the setCategory() function inside the document.ready just like in your demo and the id too is the same. Wonder whats the issue. Do let me know if you can think up something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made the following change and it worked. I am still not sure what was wrong with my earlier code. If only someone could explain.

```
 success: function(data)
    {     
        var strCategory = "<option value='-1'>My Favorites</option>";  
        strCategory += "<option value='0'>All</option>";   
        data = parseXml(data);
        $(data).find("item").each(function() 
        {       
            strCategory +="<option ";
            if(strCat == $(this).find("CategoryId").text())
            {
                strCategory += " selected=true  ";
            }
            strCategory += "value='"+$(this).find("CategoryId").text()+"'>"+$(this).find("catName").text()+"</option>" ;
        });
        $("#selectCategory").html(strCategory);
```

}